# How do I get the camera's local XYZ axis in Direct X 11?

Tags: camera, directx11, quaternion

I'm currently working on quaternion rotation and I have them working, but it seems to be using the world XYZ axis to rotate around, which is an issue as the camera rotates itself around an axis.

[image]

Similar to the last image, how do I rotate the camera around its local XYZ axis rather than the world XYZ?

**Edit**:

The camera now rotates around its local axis, but when doing so, it does not change its values in world space. I can hold a key down and it will rotate around the correct axis, but once I release the key it will snap back to its original position before the rotation began. What must I do to allow the local changes to be applied to world space?

Comment: Rotate the camera before translating it.

Comment: I post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To rotate something around it's local X, Y and Z axes instead of around the global axes you need to rotate it first and then translate it.

Comment: There is another problem with this. When I'm rotating in local space, the object doesn't update its lookat coordinates. The camera rotates around the correct axis, but when I stop rotating, it snaps back to its original position. What must I do to make it update its local values to world values?